# $LS$ vs $JJ$ coupling hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, quantum-spin

While studying $LS$ coupling, I came across the fact that it is only applicable for lighter atoms, and the perturbation term in the hamiltonian is given as:

$H_2 = A_{ij} \vec{L}.\vec{S}$, where $A_{ij}$ is some constant.
From here, we can proceed by saying,

$ \vec{L}.\vec{S} = \frac{1}{2} (J^2 - L^2 - S^2)$ where these are the total angular momenta, spin and so on. I know that these depend on the number of particles present. For two electrons for example, $l = |l_1-l_2|,....l_1+l_2$ and $s = 0,1$. However I don't see how to extend this to 3 or 4 electron systems. How can I add angular momenta that way ? Or spin for that matter ? How does the addition rule work there ?

Secondly, for heavier atoms, JJ coupling is used over LS coupling. I was wondering how is the hamiltonian modified for such a case. Does the hamiltonian become $H_2 = A_{ij} \vec{J_i}.\vec{J_j}$ ? I've seen from some online material, that the hamiltonian is written in this way, and we have :

$ \vec{J_i}.\vec{J_j} = \frac{1}{2} (J^2 - J_i^2 - J_j^2)$

However, in this case, I can't understand what $J_i$ and $J_j$ seem to represent. If they represent the total angular momenta of two different particles, how do we extend this to multiple particles.

If I'm wrong, can someone point out, what is the difference in the hamiltonian in $LS$ vs $JJ$ couplings?